# R shiny conditionPanel same filter on multiple pages

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an R shiny app with some filters that I want to apply on different pages and I want some of these filters to create extra inputs. I've been using conditionalPanel to show/hide the extra inputs but I'm having a problem with hiding the extra inputs when you go onto a different page.

In the example below if you select an age range, this age range is selected on all pages. If you select 60+ you get an additional input for gender and when you select a gender and change page this is applied on all the other pages. But, if you then select a different age range on a different page the gender conditionalPanel isn't hidden until you click on a different page. If I change the || to && in the condition statement it solves the problem I get another problem where the conditional panel doesn't show until you click on a different page.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)


agePanelUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(width = 9, 
           uiOutput(ns("select_age")))
  )
}

agePanel <- function(input, output, session, x) {
  output$select_age <- renderUI({
    input$resetInput
    radioGroupButtons(
      inputId = paste0(x, "age_choice"),
      choices = c('0-18', '19-34', "35-59", "60+"),
      selected =  '0-18')
  })
}

filterPanelUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 9, 
           uiOutput(ns('select_gender'))))
}

filterPanel <- function(input, output, session, x) {
  output$select_gender <- renderUI({
    input$resetInput
    pickerInput(
      inputId = paste0(x, "gender_choice"),
      choices = c('F', 'M'),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,`selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
}

ui <- dashboardPage(

  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "testing",
    titleWidth = 250),

  dashboardSidebar(

    width = 250,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "menu",
      menuItem("Information", tabName = "info"),
      menuItem("page 1", tabName = "page1"),
      menuItem("page 2", tabName = "page2"),
      menuItem("page 3", tabName = "page3"))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem("info"),
    tabItem(tabName = "page1", 
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_11"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "input.first_age_choice == '60+' || input.second_age_choice == '60+' || input.third_age_choice == '60+'",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_1")))),
    tabItem(tabName = "page2",
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_12"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "input.first_age_choice == '60+' || input.second_age_choice == '60+' || input.third_age_choice == '60+'",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_2"))
            )),
    tabItem(tabName = "page3",
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_13"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "input.first_age_choice == '60+' || input.second_age_choice == '60+' || input.third_age_choice == '60+'",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_3"))
            )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(module = filterPanel, id = "id_1", x = "first_")
  callModule(module = filterPanel, id = "id_2", x = "second_")
  callModule(module = filterPanel, id = "id_3", x = "third_")

  callModule(module = agePanel, id = "id_11", x = "first_")
  callModule(module = agePanel, id = "id_12", x = "second_")
  callModule(module = agePanel, id = "id_13", x = "third_")

  tab_select <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    if (input$menu == "page1") {
      tab_select$gender <- input$first_gender_choice
      tab_select$age <- input$first_age_choice
    } else if(input$menu == "page2") {
      tab_select$gender <- input$second_gender_choice
      tab_select$age <- input$second_age_choice
    } else if(input$menu == "page3") {
      tab_select$gender <- input$third_gender_choice
      tab_select$age <- input$third_age_choice
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$menu, {
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "first_gender_choice", selected = tab_select$gender)
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "second_gender_choice", selected = tab_select$gender)
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "third_gender_choice", selected = tab_select$gender)
    updateRadioGroupButtons(session, inputId = "first_age_choice", selected = tab_select$age)
    updateRadioGroupButtons(session, inputId = "second_age_choice", selected = tab_select$age)
    updateRadioGroupButtons(session, inputId = "third_age_choice", selected = tab_select$age)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out with a bit more logic in the conditionPanel condition:

```
tabItem(tabName = "page1", 
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_11"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "(input.menu == 'page1' && input.first_age_choice == '60+') || (input.menu != 'page1' && (input.second_age_choice == '60+' || input.third_age_choice == '60+'))",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_1")))),
    tabItem(tabName = "page2",
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_12"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "(input.menu == 'page2' && input.second_age_choice == '60+') || (input.menu != 'page2' && (input.first_age_choice == '60+' || input.third_age_choice == '60+'))",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_2"))
            )),
    tabItem(tabName = "page3",
            box(width = 12, status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                fluidRow(
                  column(width = 9, h4("Selection"))),

                agePanelUI(id = "id_13"),

                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "(input.menu == 'page3' && input.third_age_choice == '60+') || (input.menu != 'page3' && (input.second_age_choice == '60+' || input.first_age_choice == '60+'))",
                  filterPanelUI(id = "id_3"))
            )))))
```